# Install a library by using npm on a server

Tags: javascript, wordpress, npm, npm-install

when i want to use some library, such as [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/), i should install it by using npm or Bower:

```
npm install croppie

bower install croppie
```

As i am using a server, i dont know where is should install it. On the server? in the wordpress files? or in the same folder that contains JS file for this library.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to add script in your wordpress web app. So there are multiple ways to do so.

1) Add `<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Foliotek/Croppie/master/croppie.min.js" />`. It's better either you download this file in your file system or add a CDN link of Croppie.

2) If you have bower.json configured in your project you can use `bower install croppie` and then link it in your index.php (root file)

Answer (score 0):

If you just have copied your project over to your server, you should have a package.json file, which contains all libraries you used. (Given you saved it via `npm install croppie --save` or `npm install croppie --save-dev`)

Then you can just go into your directory which contains the package.json and run `npm install`.

If you ever install a library which you would like to use without a project, you can install it globally with `npm install libraryName -g`, thus making it available on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you develop locally and deploy to a server, you should install dependencies locally, in /wp-content/themes/(your-theme)/ and don't upload them to your web server along with the rest of the site. The .bowerrc file, placed in the theme directory, should include the target directory in which bower will place the dependencies you've required:

```
{
"directory": "bower_components"
}
```

Then you'd want to bundle those dependencies in css/js etc. directories within the theme and deploy those. `.gitignore` the `bower_components` directory or just don't FTP that directory up, depending on how you do things.